# Attempting an audio pre-amplifier circuit with falstad.com

Tags: preamp, falstad

I'm new to electronics and discovered the falstad.com simulator.  I wanted to model this audio pre-amplifier circuit:

[image]

So I went into falstad and drew this:

[My pre-amplifier circuit on falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+5.934295036739208+57+5+50%0Av+-32+256+-32+112+0+1+80+0.001+0+0+0.5%0Ag+64+320+64+368+0%0Ar+96+112+192+112+0+1000%0Ar+192+144+336+144+0+100000%0Aw+336+144+336+192+0%0Aw+192+112+192+144+0%0Aw+192+144+192+176+0%0Aa+192+192+336+192+8+12+0+1000000+5.999939984061564+5.999999999333873+100000%0Ac+96+112+-32+112+0+1.0000000000000001e-7+5.998992496464382%0Ac+128+208+128+320+0+1.0000000000000001e-7+5.999999999333873%0Ar+64+208+128+208+0+47000%0Ar+192+208+192+320+0+47000%0Aw+128+208+192+208+0%0Aw+-32+256+-32+320+0%0Aw+-32+320+64+320+0%0Aw+64+320+128+320+0%0Aw+128+320+192+320+0%0Av+64+320+64+208+0+0+40+12+0+0+0.5%0Ac+336+192+416+192+0+0.000009999999999999999+0.0010000000023389077%0Aw+416+192+464+192+2%0Ao+0+64+0+4098+0.00244140625+0.025+0+2+0+3%0Ao+19+64+0+12291+11.99912328127774+0.0001+1+2+19+3%0A)

The output voltage is showing a flat line at about 6V.   I was hoping for an amplified signal.  So I can't tell if there's something wrong with the circuit I was attempting to model of if I'm just not using falstad correctly?

Comment: increase the input signal amplitude.

Comment: And 100nF capacitor value. Because now the C1 together with 1k from a high pass filter. Fc = 0.16/Rc =1.6kHz. Hence C = 0.16/(8Hz * 1k) = 22uF

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y6wltxjm

Comment: oooh! Ok this is great, the capacitors made a filter that attenuated the AC signal.  You connected a 100k resistor from output to ground to center the wave form around 0V again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are going on here:

- First, your input coupling capacitor is way too small for that frequency. Use at least 10 µF in order to prevent attenuation at 80 Hz.
- Second, and this is peculiar to the simulator, you have no DC path to the output pin, which means that it "floats" up to 6V. You're trying to look at a 100 mV output signal (assuming you fix the first problem) superimposed on that 6V DC bias, and the simulator display simply doesn't have the resolution to show that. Add a 10k resistor from the output node to ground.

With these issues fixed, the simulator shows an output signal that's close to 100× the input signal.